# Google Graph grid lines

Tags: java, android

I want to draw a few linegraphs in a chart using the Google Chart Tools. I managed to do that and scale the axis the way I like them. But I can´t get the grid lines right. How do I set them corretly?

[MyGraph](http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?&chtt=Laura&cht=lxy&chs=250x150&chd=t:0,20,40,80%7C0,10,0,10%7C0,20,40,80%7C35,3,23,250&chf=bg,s,FF00FF&chg=20,0&chco=000000,000000&chxr=0,0,80,10%7C1,0,250,10&chds=0,80,0,250&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,ff0000,12,0,lt%7C1,0000ff,10,1,lt)

As can be seen in the URL i would like them every 20 units on the X-axis.
Same Problem on the Y-Axis.

Comment: what graph framework are you using?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea and since you didn't show any code, nor state how you are drawing the graph, I guess that I will have to remain in the dark!

Comment: Sorry about that I´m using the Google Chart API